# How to convert a string in java to be accessible for an xml TextView for android

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, textview

I'd like to take a string which was declared and assigned in MainActivity.java and have it be assigned as the text for a TextView object in a file named activity_second.xml. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure it's what you're asking since i can't see your code but i think it's;

```
String b= "This is a string variable.";
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id....);
textView2.setText(b);
```

Comment: Thanks lewis dylan Nkuranga.  Sorry my question was so vague, but your solution gave me enough insight to correct my mistakes.